# Force new lines between words in cell of org table

Tags: org-mode

I have such a table in org doc

```
(?P<name>...)
#+OPTIONS: \n:t
|---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------|
| Context of reference to group “quote”                   | Ways to reference it                      |
| ------------------------------------------------------- | ----------------------------------------- |
| in the same pattern itself                              | `(?P=quote)` (as shown)`\1`               |
|---------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------|
| when processing match object *m*                        | `m.group('quote')``m.end('quote')` (etc.) |
```

[image]

How could force new line between `(?P=quote)     as shown)1`

Reformat it as

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot with `org-type` tables. You can use `table.el-type` tables instead, but Org provides only limited support for them and you may (or may not) find the incompatibilites annoying. For example, here's the docstring of `org-table-convert` which lists some of the incompatibilities:

> Convert from Org table to table.el and back.
>   Obviously, this only works within limits.  When an Org table is converted
>   to table.el, all horizontal separator lines get lost, because table.el uses
>   these as cell boundaries and has no notion of horizontal lines.  A table.el
>   table can be converted to an Org table only if it does not do row or column
>   spanning.  Multiline cells will become multiple cells.  Beware, Org mode
>   does not test if the table can be successfully converted - it blindly
>   applies a recipe that works for simple tables.